# Receive and process email in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, exchange-server

I am looking to see if there is a viable solution to allow us to receive emails into SQL Server, process the content or linked attachments, and run a script on a database.

Currently we have a process where certain developers create basic scripts to modify one of a few of our production databases. They upload the scripts to our SVN and then email the DBA's with a link to the script. We then open it in SSMS and run, copy/pasting the output in response to the email. The process is primarily a separation of duties and to ensure that the DBA's are the only ones that can run the scripts.

But there are times when we may be unavailable and not able to be at a computer to run these in SSMS, but the business is waiting on these tables getting updated. I am trying to find a solution where we might be able to forward these emails if we see them, such as on our phones, to a receiving email on the SQL Server, and have a proc grab the script from SVN, maybe inserting the content of the script and mail into a database, and then running that script on the appropriate DB. My idea was having this on our MSX server and then it would be able to run on one of the servers via linked server or something. Then I want the output emailed back as confirmation.

I have looked around and most email related questions are about sending email. The only things I have found remotely related are about SQL Mail, which I understand is outdated and inefficient, and potentially CLR. Most of our environments are 2012+.

Am I on the right track with my thinking or is there something else I should be considering?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a SQL injection nightmare. I would not recommend this. If you are going to just automatically do this, then the separation of duty is gone and I'd just use a scripting tool outside of sql server to parse it, and an agent job to pick it up and import the script.

Comment: @scsimon This is why I am asking here. I understand there are holes in my idea so I am trying to see if there are other wars to do this. Also, the separation of duty is not necessarily gone if the DBA's are the only ones able to forward these to the server. It is not totally automatic because we are still triggering the process. We are still in between the devs and the server. Just trying to investigate potential solutions to appease the business in the instances when no one happens to be available to get online immediately. I appreciate the input though. Thanks